# how to save the selenium test script result into local host

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, automated-tests

following is the dockerfile and docker-compose file:

```
Dockerfile:
FROM python:alpine3.6
RUN pip install selenium
```

```
docker-compose.yml
version: "2.0"
services:
  test:
    image: selenium_python:v1
    volumes:
        - ./test.py:/test_script/test.py
    command: python /test_script/test.py > /home/result/result.txt
    depends_on:
      - chrome
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

trying to run the script but the result seems doesn't save to local host machine

Answer (score 0):

You are half there, just mount a local directory and send the output there.

For example with `/tmp`:

```
...
services:
  test:
    image: selenium_python:v1
    volumes:
      - ./test.py:/test_script/test.py
      - /tmp:/tmp
    command: python /test_script/test.py > /tmp/result.txt
...
```

Comment: got your point. but seem doesn't not work, i think the mapping somewhere wrong..

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do you know your script works in the container? 2) Did you check the logs?

Comment: Was there any error running the script? When you run your script, does the output go to stderr? In any case, redirect stderr to stdout by adding `2>&1` to your command.